# Setting the MySql wait_timeout session variable

Tags: java, mysql

I am currently working in a java program involving mysql. I encountered a ***problem*** with these message:

> Communications link failure. The last packet successfully received
>   from the server was 174,165,153 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent
>   successfully to the server was 4 milliseconds ago.

I believe this has to do with the session variable 'wait_timeout'. My assumption could be wrong though so I am confirming it here. Is this really because of the 'wait_timeout' session variable? Does this error mean that my database connection is "expired" in a sense that the session timeout already lapsed? If yes, I have another problem.. I cannot reproduce the said error..

This is what I am trying in order to replicate the error.

1. Setting the `wait_timeout` variable to `5` which is originally `28800`( 8 hrs ).

   `mysql> set session wait_timeout=5;`
2. Thinking that my next attempt to access database would apply this, I would run this code:

   ```
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       oConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(sUrl,sUser,sPass);
       System.out.println("Database Connection Established.\n");
       Thread.sleep(6000);

       executeSimpleQuery();
   ```

   The `executeSimpleQuery()` function just executes a simple `SELECT * FROM` statement to check if the connection is still working. Apparently, if the wait_timeout is just 5 and I've made the thread sleep for 6 seconds, the connection would now be expired and the error should be produced. But, the expected result does not happen instead it performs the query.

What should i do to replicate the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set wait_timeout=5 for current session; then opened another session (in java application) and executed the query. Try to set this variable after the opening connection, or set it globally.

For example -

```
SET @@global.wait_timeout = 15; -- Set global variable
SET @@local.wait_timeout = 25; -- Set session variable
SELECT @@global.wait_timeout, @@local.wait_timeout; -- Check global and session variables
```

Comment: thank you very much for this. although i did not use the global setting of the wait_timeout because i need to handle connection per session. thanks again